# responsive menu is not working in my website what I am Missing

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/style_inventive.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

where style_inventive.css is style sheet I am using for menu

here is CSS file contents

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
.navbar-right .dropdown-menu {

   right: auto; 

 }}

 .nav>li>a:hover
  {
    background-color: #336699;
    color:#fff;
   }
  .dropdown-menu
  {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top :0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    color: #fff;
  }
 .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover
  {
      background-color: #336699;
      color:#fff;
  }

  .dropdown-menu li
   {
     height: 40;
     color: #fff;
     float: none;
     display: block;
     margin: 0;
     text-align: left;
     border: 0;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  }
  .dropdown-menu a
  {     
     margin-top: 10;    
  }
```

Here is HTML Code for menu

```
<div class="col-sm-7 menu">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">        
                <li><a href="home_inventive.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown" id="licompany">
                    <a href="#" id="acompany" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">COMPANY </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="about_us.html">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="team.html">Meet The Team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="join_us.html">Join Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">SERVICE </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="mobile_app_development.html">Mobile App Development</a></li>
                        <li><a href="software_development.html">Software Development</a></li>
                        <li><a href="web_development.html"> Web development</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>                   
                <li><a href="product.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">TECHNOLOGY </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="php.html">PHP</a></li>
                        <li><a href="java.html">JAVA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="android.html">Android</a></li>
                        <li><a href="dotnet.html">.Net</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ios.html">iOS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="sitemap.html">SITEMAP</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>                                       
    </div>
```

Except menu, everything is shown when I resize my browser.
Menu is not shown when I resize.

Comment: you have not used `bootstrap.min.js` you need to use that & also jquery!

Comment: please provide fiddle.

Comment: did you include external jquery library? see this: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated html structure according to bootstrap [example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) its working.

1. if you see bootstrap example thay used `navbar-header` outside the
   `collapse navbar-collapse` but in your case you missed it.
2. second you'r targeting `navbar-responsive-collapse` in
   `data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse"` but you have not define
   it in with `navbar-collapse` so i just add example targeted ID
   `data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"` and define it in `<div
   class="collapse navbar-collapse"
   id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">`.
3. I just take another element `navbar navbar-default` inside `col-sm-7
   menu` this is important thing that you have missed  without the `navbar`
   class its obviously will not work.

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tL164k46/2/)

```
<div class="col-sm-7 menu">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="home_inventive.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown" id="licompany">
          <a href="#" id="acompany" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">COMPANY </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="about_us.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="team.html">Meet The Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="join_us.html">Join Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">SERVICE </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="mobile_app_development.html">Mobile App Development</a></li>
            <li><a href="software_development.html">Software Development</a></li>
            <li><a href="web_development.html"> Web development</a></li>

          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="product.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">TECHNOLOGY </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="php.html">PHP</a></li>
            <li><a href="java.html">JAVA</a></li>
            <li><a href="android.html">Android</a></li>
            <li><a href="dotnet.html">.Net</a></li>
            <li><a href="ios.html">iOS</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="sitemap.html">SITEMAP</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have add some code that may b not in your code
working model

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
    right: auto;
  }
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #336699;
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #336699;
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  height: 40;
  color: #fff;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  margin-top: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-container" id="navbar-container">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle menu-toggler pull-left fixed" id="menu-toggler" data-target="#sidebar">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle sidebar</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar">
                </span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">


      <div class="col-sm-7 menu">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="home_inventive.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown" id="licompany">
              <a href="#" id="acompany" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">COMPANY </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="about_us.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="team.html">Meet The Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="join_us.html">Join Us</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">SERVICE </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="mobile_app_development.html">Mobile App Development</a></li>
                <li><a href="software_development.html">Software Development</a></li>
                <li><a href="web_development.html"> Web development</a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="product.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">TECHNOLOGY </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="php.html">PHP</a></li>
                <li><a href="java.html">JAVA</a></li>
                <li><a href="android.html">Android</a></li>
                <li><a href="dotnet.html">.Net</a></li>
                <li><a href="ios.html">iOS</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="sitemap.html">SITEMAP</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BDhara/tL164k46/1/)

Comment: check demo n resize result..button is appear on resize of window..OP missed lots of code that's why menu doesnot show properly

Answer (score 1):

Check with this below code following changes i have made in your code have a look

1st you have missed out `<nav class="navbar navbar-default">` for navbar and 2nd you have missed `<div class="navbar-header">` mobile screen navbar if you miss parent class it will apply class and also menu will be not be responsive.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px){
.navbar-right .dropdown-menu {

   right: auto; 

 }}

 .nav>li>a:hover
  {
    background-color: #336699 !important;
    color:#fff !important;
   }
  .dropdown-menu
  {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top :0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
 .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover
  {
      background-color: #336699 !important;
      color:#fff !important;
  }

  .dropdown-menu li
   {
     height: 40;
     color: #fff;
     float: none;
     display: block;
     margin: 0;
     text-align: left;
     border: 0;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  }
  .dropdown-menu a
  {     
     margin-top: 10;    
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-sm-7 menu">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="home_inventive.html">HOME</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown" id="licompany">
            <a href="#" id="acompany" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">COMPANY </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="about_us.html">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="team.html">Meet The Team</a></li>
              <li><a href="join_us.html">Join Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">SERVICE </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="mobile_app_development.html">Mobile App Development</a></li>
              <li><a href="software_development.html">Software Development</a></li>
              <li><a href="web_development.html"> Web development</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>                   
          <li><a href="product.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">TECHNOLOGY </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="php.html">PHP</a></li>
              <li><a href="java.html">JAVA</a></li>
              <li><a href="android.html">Android</a></li>
              <li><a href="dotnet.html">.Net</a></li>
              <li><a href="ios.html">iOS</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="sitemap.html">SITEMAP</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Include This Js at top / bottom of the page